# Can you rethrow a .NET exception on a different thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

Is it legal and safe in C# to catch an exception on one thread, and then re-throw it on another.

E.g. is this legal

```
Exception localEx = null;

Thread mythread = new Thread() { () =>
                   {
                        try
                        {
                            DoSomeStuff();
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            localEx = ex;
                        }
                    });

myThread.Start();
...
myThread.Join();

if(localEx != null)
   throw localEx;    // rethrow on the main thread
```

I think it is legal, but I'm having trouble finding any doco that proves it.  The closest I found was a brief mention of transferring exceptions between threads here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229005.aspx

Comment: Can you pass an object from a thread to another?

Comment: @Partial: of course you can.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it's legal. Exceptions are (generally speaking) descriptive objects with no thread affinity.

You'd be better off wrapping your thread exception in a new exception:

```
throw new Exception("Something descriptive here", localEx);
```

That way, the stack trace in localEx will be preserved (as the `InnerException` of the new exception).

Comment: -1: Are you planning to add a citation? If so, I'll upvote then.

Comment: Your answer was "yes, it's legal". I think more is required than that. You've expanded your answer to the point where the downvote is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is not a rethrow. It's a new throw of an exception instance you happened to have in a variable. Even if you were using only a single thread, this would be a bad idea, as it makes the exception look like it came from the "throw" site. With multiple threads, I have no idea how anyone would figure out there had been a thread change.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. [System.AggregateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception%28VS.100%29.aspx) is added to .NET 4 for specifically that purpose during parallel operations.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why it wouldn't work, but you need to remember that you aren't actually rethrowing the exception. You are throwing a new exception, that just happens to be the same exception object. So, for example, the stack trace will say it was thrown from "throw localEx;" instead of wherever the original exception came from.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, rethrow was the wrong word.  I'll use localEx as inner exception to avoid the call stack problem you mention.

Answer (score 2):

It is legal and it isn't a rethrow, it's a new exception being thrown on another thread (with the same exception object)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you think its not legal. If it were illegal surely the compiler would catch or the runtime would throw an exception. As a matter of fact I use this pattern.
@John In a windows forms app that calls web services using a background thread I use this way. The exception is then handled in the Application.ThreadException top level handler, logged etc. It is unnecessary to know in which thread the exception occured.